# How to get all list filed information with PnP for SharePointOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

When I use Get-PnPField It just output Title, InternalName and ID.
I'd like to output ColumnType, DefaultValue, Choices etc..

If anyone knows, could you give me an idea?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `Get-PnPField` is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field.

We could get the default value and column type this way:

```
$field=Get-PnPField -List "test" -Identity "cks"
$field.DefaultValue
$field.SchemaXml
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.
It was very helpful.